# Palantir Foundry spark.sql query

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, palantir-foundry

When I attempt to query my input table as a view, I get the error `com.palantir.foundry.spark.api.errors.DatasetPathNotFoundException`. My code is as follows:

```
def Median_Product_Revenue_Temp2(Merchant_Segments):

    Merchant_Segments.createOrReplaceTempView('Merchant_Segments_View')
    df = spark.sql('select * from Merchant_Segments_View limit 5')  
    return df
```

I need to dynamically query this table, since I am trying to calculate the median using `percentile_approx` across numerous fields, and I'm not sure how to do this without using `spark.sql`.

If I try to avoid using `spark.sql` to calculate median across numerous fields using something like the below code, it results in the error `Missing Transform Attribute: A module object does not have an attribute percentile_approx. Please check the spelling and/or the datatype of the object.`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F 

exprs = {x: percentile_approx("x", 0.5) for x in df.columns if x is not exclustion_list}
df = df.groupBy(['BANK_NAME','BUS_SEGMENT']).agg(exprs)
```

Answer (score 1):

try `createGlobalTempView`. It worked for me.

eg:

```
df.createGlobalTempView("people")
```

(Don't know the root cause why `localTempView` dose not work )

Answer (score 0):

I managed to avoid using dynamic sql for calculating median across columns using the following code:

```
df_result = df.groupBy(group_list).agg(
    *[ F.expr('percentile_approx(nullif('+col+',0), 0.5)').alias(col) for col in df.columns if col not in exclusion_list]
)
```

Embedding `percentile_approx` in an `F.expr` bypassed the issue I was encountering in the second half of my post.